# Outlook Inbox after spoofing attack is empty. Incoming mails not coming through in Inbox

Tags: microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office, mail-forwarding, spoofing

Supposedly, a spoofing mail was sent to a internal and hundreds of external people from our user's account last Wednesday. Since Friday afternoon, her Outlook Inbox is shown empty and  she is not able to receive incoming mails since then. Outgoing mail works. Checked both Outlook client and web client. Made some tests from admin account to send and receive mails. The sent mails are shown in user's sent items folder but her inbox is empty. Even if you enter a specific sender’s name in the search bar in Inbox then you see the (not received) incoming mails displayed and are thus already mark as read. We checked all user Settings (mail-forwarding rules) etc. and in our Windows AD, O365 admin portal, Azure AD and Exchange. All look good. No rules set beforehand. Major concern is that the user’s inbox is wiped out and no new mails coming. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `Even if you enter a specific sender’s name in the search bar in Inbox then you see the (not received) incoming mails displayed and are thus already mark as read.` - That doesn't quite make sense. The Inbox is empty but searching for a particular sender in the Inbox shows results?

Comment: Hi, figured it out. In Outlook Desktop Client it wouldn't Show any rules set. However, logged into user's account via OWA and checked into the Settings. The Mail-forwarding rule was set and all the Incoming mails were diverted to a Folder called "RSS Subscriptions". Thus it solved the issue by removing off of the rule. Thanks for your Reply.